# Ackermann-Péter function call count using Writer monad

Tags: recursion, haskell, mathematics, monads

I'm quite new to Monads and I tried add function call counting to the Ackermann function code. The goal was simplicity, not [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104459/haskell-ackermann-function). I want to have code review on the `ackCount` function.

```hs
module AckermannPeterWrite where

import Data.Monoid
import Control.Monad.Writer (Writer, tell, runWriter)

ackCount :: Int -> Int -> Writer (Sum Int) Int
ackCount m n
  | m == 0 = do
            tell (Sum 1)
            return $ n + 1
  | (m > 0) && (n == 0) = do
            tell (Sum 1)
            ackCount (m-1) 1
  | (m > 0) && (n > 0)  = do
            tell (Sum 1)
            let (secondArg, count) = runWriter $ (ackCount m (n-1))
            tell (Sum $ getSum count)
            ackCount (m-1) secondArg

ackCountMain :: Int -> Int -> String
ackCountMain m n = do
    let (result, count) = runWriter $ ackCount m n
    "A(" ++ show m ++ ", " ++ show n ++ ") == " ++ show result ++ ",         " ++ show (getSum count) ++ " function calls"

main :: IO ()
main = do
   putStrLn $ ackCountMain 0 77
   putStrLn $ ackCountMain 0 9
   putStrLn $ ackCountMain 1 9
   putStrLn $ ackCountMain 2 9
   putStrLn $ ackCountMain 3 6
```

Bonus. A code that gives the same result without monads.

```hs
ackCounter :: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)
ackCounter (m, sm) (n, sn)
  | m == 0              = (n + 1, sm+sn+1)
  | (m > 0) && (n == 0) = let (res, s) = ackCounter (m-1, 0) (1, 0) in (res, s+sm+sn+1)
  | (m > 0) && (n > 0)  = 
                let (res, s) = ackCounter (m-1, 0) (ackCounter (m, 0) (n-1, 0))
                in (res, s+sm+sn+1)

ackC :: Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)
ackC m n = ackCounter (m, 0) (n, 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out is these lines:

```hs
            let (secondArg, count) = runWriter $ ackCount m (n-1)
            tell (Sum $ getSum count)
```

You're not really *using* the monad you're using; the whole point is for the accumulation to happen in the background:

```hs
            secondArg <- ackCount m (n-1)
```

Other than that, it's mostly good!

It's a good idea to make your functions total, even if that means including an
`| otherwise = error "message"` clause.
Alternately, you can avoid all your `< 0` by retyping your function in terms of `Natural`s. Unfortunately, there's no first-class `Natural` data-type in Haskell, I found two options: [natural-numbers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/natural-numbers-0.1.2.0) and [naturals](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/naturals-0.2.0.2), each of which deals with the problems in different ways. ([See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884220/is-there-a-practical-way-of-using-natural-numbers-in-haskell))

Finally, with a little reorganization, you can avoid repeating the call to `tell $ Sum 1` for every case.

This tests as correct for small values :)

```hs
ackNew :: Natural -> Natural -> Writer (Sum Natural) Natural
ackNew m n = do tell $ Sum 1
                case (m, n) of
                  (0, _) -> return $ n + 1
                  (_, 0) -> ackNew (m - 1) 1
                  _      -> do secondArg <- ackNew m (n - 1)
                               ackNew (m - 1) secondArg
```

Comment: Haskell has had `Numeric.Natural` since base-4.8.0.0 in 2015.

Comment: You're right! Sorry I failed to find it. The documentation at [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Numeric-Natural.html#t:Natural) raises more questions than it answers, but it seems to work in my code, changing nothing but the `import`.